# I need to send a slack message when a collection.find finds a task in failure in a mongodb database

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I need to be able to send a message to slack with the name of the collection in `MongoDB` when the query `collection.find()` finds in the DB a `task_status` in failure. So far it's what I've got and it works but I need the message to say the name of the collection, as this code is supposed to be used in a DB with a lot of collections, can someone help me?

```
import pymongo
import requests
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient

def slackmessage ():
    wekbook_url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/*****'
    slack_data = {
        'text': "There is problem in your mongodb collection, task is in FAILURE.",
        'username': 'MongodbAlert',
        'icon_emoji': ':fire:'
    }
    response = requests.post(wekbook_url, data = json.dumps(slack_data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

def mongodbfind ():
    cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://*****")
    db = cluster["nameofthemongodb"]
    collection = db["nameofthecollection"]
    mysearch = collection.find({ "task_status":"FAILURE"})
    for x in mysearch:
        print (m + str(x))
        return True
        
if mongocheck() == True:
    slackmessage()
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you've pasted actually calls `slackmessage`.

Comment: How and where are you calling the slackmessage function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass collection name in slackmessage() function, and concatenate it with text in slack_data:

```
def slackmessage (collectionName):
    wekbook_url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/*****'
    slack_data = {
        'text': "There is problem in your mongodb collection - "+collectionName+", task is in FAILURE.",
        'username': 'MongodbAlert',
        'icon_emoji': ':fire:'
    }
    response = requests.post(wekbook_url, data = json.dumps(slack_data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

# call the function with connectionname as argument
slackmessage(collectionName)
```

Comment: Thanks it helped to change my code and it's already working as intended.